# SonataAdminBundle: set permission depending on field value

Tags: symfony, acl, sonata-admin

I have a working SonataAdmin+FOSUser (WITHOUT SonataUserBundle) setup with roles and ACL enabled. This is working fine, every user has access to different admins depending on their roles.

Now I need to go a bit deeper. I would like to restrict access to one of the admin depending on the value of an association of the underlying entity.

Lets say I have this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Content
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ContentType", inversedBy="contents")
     */
    private $type;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ContentType
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;
}
```

I would like the following:

- Users with ROLE_XXXXX : have access to all contents with content type name 'XXXXX'
- Users with ROLE_YYYYY : have access to all contents with content type name 'YYYYY'
  ...

Of course it also means that when creating a new content or filtering the list of contents, users should not be able to select a content type on which they don't have any permission.

I have tried this with no luck:

```
php app/console acl:set --role=ROLE_XXXXX MASTER MyBundle/ContentType:2
```